# Cygnus-NGSI won't save data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, fiware-cygnus

Im trying to save some data in a postgreSQL database using cygnus-ngsi, but nothing happens. Im running all services in a docker container using docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
cygnus:
 image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest
 hostname: cygnus
 container_name: cygnus_fiware
 volumes:
   - ./config/cygnus/cygnus.conf:/opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf
   - ./config/cygnus/grouping_rules.conf:/opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf
 links:
   - orion
   - postgres
 expose:
   - "5050"
 ports:
   - "5050:5050" 

postgres:
 restart: always
 image: postgres:latest
 container_name: postgres_fiware
 volumes:
   - ./data/db/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"
 expose:
   - "5432"
 environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=teste
   - POSTGRES_DB=newdb
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456789
```

agent.conf

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = postgresql-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = postgresql-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = postgresql-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
# URL target
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
# default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
# source interceptors, do not change
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupingInterceptor, do not change
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# see the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# NGSIPostgreSQLSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.channel = postgresql-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink
# true applies the new encoding, false applies the old encoding.
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_encoding = false
# true if name mappings are enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_grouping = false
# true if lower case is wanted to forced in all the element names, false otherwise
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_lowercase = false
# the FQDN/IP address where the PostgreSQL server runs
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_host = postgres
# the port where the PostgreSQL server listens for incomming connections
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_port = 5432
# the name of the postgresql database
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_database = newdb
# a valid user in the PostgreSQL server
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_username = teste
# password for the user above
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_password = 123456789
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.attr_persistence = row
# select the data_model: dm-by-service-path or dm-by-entity
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_size = 100
# timeout for batch accumulation
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_timeout = 30
# number of retries upon persistence error
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_ttl = 10




# =============================================
# postgresql-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Messages from docker-compose:

```
cygnus_fiware | time=2017-06-19T15:11:15.132Z | lvl=WARN | corr=4af15a0c-5501-11e7-aa0a-0242ac130004 | trans=508576db-1443-4c64-bfc9-629d1a0b250e | srv=espometeo | subsrv=/environment | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[257] : [NGSIRestHandler] Unnecessary header
cygnus_fiware | time=2017-06-19T15:11:15.133Z | lvl=INFO | corr=89ac4c66-5501-11e7-850f-0242ac130004 | trans=3ae0dc99-de51-49a3-937f-42d887b7e7d7 | srv=espometeo | subsrv=/environment | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[282] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (3ae0dc99-de51-49a3-937f-42d887b7e7d7)
cygnus_fiware | time=2017-06-19T15:11:15.133Z | lvl=INFO | corr=89ac4c66-5501-11e7-850f-0242ac130004 | trans=3ae0dc99-de51-49a3-937f-42d887b7e7d7 | srv=espometeo | subsrv=/environment | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[299] : [NGSIRestHandler] Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "5947d328e143997a02b11008",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "type" : "EstacaoMeteo",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "Estacao3",        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "Humidity",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "35.3",            "metadatas" : [              {                "name" : "TimeInstant",                "type" : "ISO8601",                "value" : "2017-06-24T13:03:00"              }            ]          },          {            "name" : "Temperature",            "type" : "float",            "value" : "15.2",            "metadatas" : [              {                "name" : "TimeInstant",                "type" : "ISO8601",                "value" : "2017-06-24T13:03:00"              }            ]          }        ]      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})



cygnus_fiware | time=2017-06-19T15:11:36.141Z | lvl=INFO | corr=89ac4c66-5501-11e7-850f-0242ac130004 | trans=3ae0dc99-de51-49a3-937f-42d887b7e7d7 | srv=espometeo | subsrv=/environment | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=persistAggregation | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink[479] : [postgresql-sink] Persisting data at NGSIPostgreSQLSink. Schema (espometeo), Table (environment_estacao3_estacaometeo), Fields ((recvTimeTs,recvTime,fiwareServicePath,entityId,entityType,attrName,attrType,attrValue,attrMd)), Values (('1497885075139','2017-06-19T15:11:15.139Z','/environment','Estacao3','EstacaoMeteo','Humidity','float','35.3','[{"name":"TimeInstant","type":"ISO8601","value":"2017-06-24T13:03:00"}]'),('1497885075139','2017-06-19T15:11:15.139Z','/environment','Estacao3','EstacaoMeteo','Temperature','float','15.2','[{"name":"TimeInstant","type":"ISO8601","value":"2017-06-24T13:03:00"}]'))
cygnus_fiware | time=2017-06-19T15:11:36.142Z | lvl=WARN | corr=89ac4c66-5501-11e7-850f-0242ac130004 | trans=3ae0dc99-de51-49a3-937f-42d887b7e7d7 | srv=espometeo | subsrv=/environment | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=processNewBatches | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[541] :
```

Seems like cygnus is getting all the data from the Orion and putting it right, but when i go to the postgresql db, there nothing. Some one already have this problem?

Persistance ERROR message:

```
cygnus_fiware | time=2017-06-22T09:45:06.092Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=processRollbackedBatches | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[398] : CygnusPersistenceError. -, null. Stack trace: [com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink.persistAggregation(NGSIPostgreSQLSink.java:504), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink.persistBatch(NGSIPostgreSQLSink.java:231), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processRollbackedBatches(NGSISink.java:390), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:372), org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68), org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]
```

Cygnus start ERRORS:

```
cygnus_fiware | + exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp '/opt/apache-flume/conf:/opt/apache-flume/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf -n cygnus-ngsi -p 8081
cygnus_fiware | /opt/apache-flume/bin/cygnus-flume-ng: line 232: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
cygnus_fiware | /opt/apache-flume/bin/cygnus-flume-ng: line 232: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you see the content of `espometeo` schema? How about the `environment_estacao3_estacaometeo` table? Is there some error related to the whole process?

Comment: The only errror i see is JAVA_HOME is not set, but i cant fix it either. I cannot see espometeo schema because the database is empty. I already tryed to create the schema and the table, but nothing happens.

Comment: From the [Cygnus documentation](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.2/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink/):
`PostgreSQL databases naming conventions

Previous to any operation with PostgreSQL you need to create the database to be used.

It must be said PostgreSQL only accepts alphanumeric characters and the underscore (_). All the other characters will be escaped to underscore (_) when composing the table names.` Are you right you have created both schema and table?

Comment: Yes, and still no data on it. Do i need to create the fields too?? Because i didnt try that.

Comment: I think you can review the documentation, mainly related to configuration and default setup for names... Try to find some log too and see possible error messages.

Comment: Well i see nothing happening, cygnus is not persisting the data in the postgre, i created all schema->table->fields and no data. I make my configuration based on the MariaDB but i see zero Postgres implementations, all should work fine but it's not.

Comment: I see you use `newdb` as database, but the message talk about `espometeo` schema... is there something misconfigured?

Comment: Im new at PostgreSQL, but as i read, you can have a database(newdb) inside that db a schema(espometeo) that will contain tables(environment_estacao3_estacaometeo) and some fields(...).
Orion is give the notification to cygnus:5050/notity, and cygnus uses the PostgresSink to put the ngsi data in a format that postgres can read, but it should de inserted in the database. My problem is in that point, i made all the configurations and no data. And i see no Postgres implemations using Orion-Cygnus-Postgres in the internet.

Comment: Are you right the database/schema/table is empty? It is difficult to predict what is if we do not have some error message... I recommend you also set properly the JAVA_HOME in the path.

Comment: I added and error message at the original post. And how can i set JAVA_HOME i tried but without any success.

Comment: I solved the issue by changing false to true in agent.conf file:
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.backend.enable_cache = true

Comment: Good! Put your answer for the question. This way, other people can be helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing false to true in agent.conf file: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.backend.enable_cache = true.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with PostgreSQL sink when cache is not enabled. It is described at [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/1446) issue.

Comment: Thanks, i already soldved the issue n a previous comment. I should had posted it already as last comment.