# Fiware-Cygnus configuration to Postgresql, DynamoDB and CKAN

Tags: postgresql, amazon-dynamodb, fiware, ckan, fiware-cygnus

I'm new to working with Fiware and have installed contextBroker and Cygnus.
What I need to do now is configure to post data to PostgreSQL, DynamoDB and CKAN.

I have seen some exampled on posting to CKAN but haven't been able to try this out as yet.

For the Amazon DynamoDB sink, I'm getting an of error that states the region that I'm using "ap-southeast-2" is invalid.  The log states that the valid region should be "ap-shouteast-2".  Has anybody else had this issue and know how to address this?

Here is the extract from the log:-

> *time=2017-07-06T08:44:39.652Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=configure |
>   msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIDynamoDBSink[108] :
>   [dynamodb-sink] Invalid configuration (region=ap-southeast-2) -- Must
>   be 'us-east-1', 'us-west-1', 'us-west-2',  'eu-west-1',
>   'eu-central-1', 'ap-northeast-1', 'ap-northeast1', 'ap-shouteast-1', **'ap-shouteast-2'** or 'sa-east-1'*

I'm also struggling to find any examples on how to Post to PostgreSQL, including any mappings for creating the table.

Are there any good examples out there on how to post to PostgreSQL, Dynamodb and CKAN?

Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `ap-southeast-2`, which should be the correct, by `ap-shouteast-2` as stated in the error message? Maybe it was a typo someone made on the code...

Comment: Yes I did a test with ap-shouteast-2 and that failed as it should.  But I managed to get the DynamoDB part working when I switched to us-east-2.
I'm still stuck on how to setup and post to PostgreSQL though.

Comment: Did you ser this observation about a problem with PostgreSQL and cygnus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658851/cygnus-ngsi-wont-save-data-in-postgresql/44839956#44839956 ?

Comment: Yes I have enable_cache set to true in the agent.  My problem is that I don't have any example to work with which would help explain what I'm missing.  I have psql running and can connect to the Amazon Postgres End Point to see the database, schema and tables.  No data is getting into any tables I create and I'm just guessing how the columns and table names are supposed to be defined.

Comment: Did you see this documentation: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink.md ?

Comment: That's where I started with the PostgreSQL configuration. 
Kind of guessing how to configure all the parts as the example isn't clear.  For instance it doesn't indicate how to define the columns and it doesn't provide any examples on how to post to this.
My postgresql post is hitting the server now but for some reason it is failing with password authentication.  Odd seeing as I can connect remotely using psql using the same password

Comment: Fix one of the issues I have, i.e. Postgresql.  Username is case sensitive when entering into the Agent_x.conf that was causing the password authentication issue.
I must say though after reading the similar post mentioned above Iwas under the impression that you had to create the Schema and Table for Cygnus PostgreSQL to work,  Not so when I submitted, it created both of these for me and not in the naming format that I was led to believe, i.e. x002f<svcPath>xffff<entityId>xffff<entityType> , instead it used <svcPath>_<entityId>_<entityType>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your post, it has revealed a bug regarding the AWS region names. Southeast regions are coded as `APSHOUTEAST1` and `APSHOUTEAST2`, instead of `APSOUTHEAST1` and `APSOUTHEAST2` (after removing `-` and upper casing the configured region). You can see it here:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/cygnus-ngsi/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus/sinks/NGSIDynamoDBSink.java#L51

The only possible workaround is to use a different region than southeast ones.

With regards to the behaviour of the sinks, usually they are able to work in two different persistence modes, "row" and "column". The former enables Cygnus to create everything, i.e. schemas and tables. The later requires schemas and tables are previously created by the admin. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink.md#section2.3.2).

Finally, the xXXXX-like encoding you are experiencing is the result of configuring `enable_encoding = true`. Just set it to `false` and you will see the underscores in the table names. More details can be seen [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink.md#about-the-encoding).